# MembershipService.ChangePassword doesn't change password issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

`MembershipService.ChangePassword` doesn't change password issue. I have no clue why...

```
var userUsers = from n in db.aspnet_Users where n.UserId == id select n;
                string userName = userUsers.Single<aspnet_Users>().UserName;

                MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(userName, false);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    string generatedPassword = user.ResetPassword();
                    if (MembershipService.ChangePassword(userName, generatedPassword, model.NewPassword))
                    {   

// So it doesn't change the password
```

Comment: have you putted a break point on the `if (user != null)` line to check if the user is really being selected? Are you getting any errors or the password just don't change? Have you called `db.SaveChanges();` after the operation?

Comment: @rcdmk Have I use db.SaveChanges() after MembershipService.ChangePassword ?

Comment: Nope. Only if you stored the password in your db or made some change to it. I'm just gessing possible mistakes cause I don't know the rest of the code. Have you any other relevant code in this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479021.aspx) out in the documentation:

> ChangePassword returns `true` if the password was updated successfully.
>   Otherwise, it returns `false`.

Before changing a password, `ChangePassword` calls the provider's overridable `OnValidatingPassword` method to validate the new password. It then **changes the password or cancels the action based on the outcome of the call**.

> If the user name, password, new password, or password answer is not
>   valid, `ChangePassword` does not throw an exception; it simply returns
>   false.

Following a successful password change, `ChangePassword` updates the user's `LastPasswordChangedDate`.

This helped me once when I had the exact same problem. The password was not valid so the method never actually changed it. I changed some password configuration in the `web.config` file and then it finally worked.

Check this lines of your web.config, this might be the problem:

```
<membership defaultProvider="Demo_MemberShipProvider">
    <providers>
       <add name="Demo_MemberShipProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
            connectionStringName="cnn"
            enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
            **enablePasswordReset="true"**
            **requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"**
            applicationName="/"
            requiresUniqueEmail="false"
            passwordFormat="Hashed"
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
            **minRequiredPasswordLength="5"**
            **minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"**
           passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="">
    </providers>
</membership>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do you still have this config settings that you changed in `web.config`? If so, can you post it on your answer?